# Laravel This page isn’t working currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've deployed my laravel project in hosting server.Copy my all contents to public_html,moved the contents of public folder to root directory.
Then changed the config/app.php lines
from,

```
 require __DIR__.'../vendor/autoload.php';
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to,

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But I got the error,

```
This page isn’t working
www.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

In my error_log getting,

```
[12-Jul-2018 07:51:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined 
function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/move/public_html/MoveAdmin/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php:363
Stack trace:
#0 /home/move/public_html/MoveAdmin/vendor/symfony/polyfill- 
mbstring/bootstrap.php(32): 
Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\Mbstring::mb_strpos(NULL, 
'/json', 0, 'UTF-8') #1 
/home/move/public_html/MoveAdmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate
/Support/Str.php(103): mb_strpos(NULL, '/json')
```

But In my hosting  server iconv is enabled.Then why do I'm getting this error?How may I solve this issue?

Comment: *Copy my all contents to public_html,moved the contents of public folder to root directory*. Shouldn't this be the other way around? Put everything in the root, and the contents of the `public` folder to `public_html`?

Comment: I've tried that gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try this in public_html/index.php :

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return base_path().'/public_html/';
});
```

Comment: I've tried by add these line in public_html/index.php at the end of the file.But gives the same error.

Comment: Is that  because of missing extension?

Comment: be sure that you have php-iconv and php-mbstring installed on server

Answer (score 0):

1. clear all file in /storage/framework/views
2. and refresh your page.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the PHP version to like 7.2 work for me

Comment: Please elaborate on why PHP 7.2 should solve the problem?